# Data Bindings across template tags

Tags: polymer

I'm wondering, is there a possibility to have databindings "out of" a template? Say I have a `<template/>`-Tag somewhere which I put into the slot of a different component - that component stamps it to its context. Then I want to bind data from the root element to the `<template/>`-Tag. Also, event bindings (on-x-changed) don't work, because you can't assign a function which is defined in the hosting component. Any ideas?

Example:

```
... host
{{boundData}}
<binding-component>
    <template>
        {{boundData}}
    </template>
</binding-component>
```

I don't see changes when I observe `boundData` in the hosting component. Is there a way to get around this? Or is firing a custom event my only chance?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for binding a property outside of polymer something like from index.html you may bind value with  element. an example ; `index.html`

```
 <dom-bind>
    <template>
      <binding-component bound-data="{{boundData}}"></binding-component>
    </template>
 </dom-bind>

  <script>
     // set a value a string, Number or Object etc.
     // Optionally wrap this code into a listener ie;
     // window.addEventListener('load', e=> { ...below code ... })
    var boundData= document.querySelector('dom-bind');
    boundData = {} // 

  </script>
```

Now in your `binding-component` element has a property as `boundData` 
hope its helps or provide more code to understand better.

Comment: thanks, I made it work with this. However, I had a more comfortable solution which I'm using now, as suggested on slack. I'll write an answer below. Still, +1

Answer (score 1):

I've made it work the way `dom-if` does it, too. Like in `dom-if` ([reference](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/lib/elements/dom-if.html#L196)), I'm creating a `Templatize`-instance which then uses `forwardHostProp` to handle the "inside"-properties

```
    this.__ctor = Templatize.templatize(template, this, {
        mutableData: true,
        forwardHostProp(prop, value) {
            // handling item updates, item being the only property 
            // from within the binding component
            // everything else is automatically bound by templatize
            this.set(prop, value);
            this.update(this.item);
        },
    });

    this.__instance = new this.__ctor();
    this.root.appendChild(this.__instance.root);
```

This all happens in `connectedCallback`.

Because the `Templatize`-instance is passed `this`, it's bound to the current context as well.

Good luck!